# Nginx и ошибка в chrome net::err_spdy_protocol_error

Tags: wordpress, nginx, ssl

После перевода сайтов на https вылезла следующая проблема: если на странице много картинок или других подключаемых файлов (js скрипты, css файлы и т.п) - они грузятся через раз. Chrome и подобные показывают ошибку net::err_spdy_protocol_error при попытке загрузки (причем если нажать на ссылку, у которой вылезла ошибка - картинка откроется), firefox ошибок не показывает, но некоторые картинки не отображаются (причем не отображаются рандомно, т.е вопрос не в отсутствии файлов). В логах сервера ошибок нет, в access.log - отданная картинка со статусом 200. Сайтов 2, оба на wordpress, картина одинаковая на обоих. По http страница открывается без каких либо проблем.

Сбрасывать и переставлять браузер пробовал, проблему не решает, да и ошибки эти появляются только на сайтах, которые на этом сервере, т.е. проблема серверная, судя по всему.

На сервере установлена freebsd 11.1 с последними обновлениями, nginx, php-fpm и mariaDB в качестве бд. Весь софт обновлен до последних версий (обновление проблему не решило).

Текущие ssl настройки nginx:

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/tso/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/tso/privkey.pem;

ssl_session_timeout 1h;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:16m;
#ssl_session_tickets off;

# Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
ssl_dhparam         /usr/local/etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

# intermediate configuration. tweak to your needs.
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains;";

# OCSP Stapling ---
# fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
```

Пробовал разные варианты для ssl_ciphers и других ssl настроек - проблему не решает, если раскомментировать опцию ssl_session_tickets off - сайт не грузится с ошибкой ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Если кто сталкивался с чем-то подобным - подскажите, плиз, в чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: Как переводили сайты на https? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562/220220

Comment: Переводил заменой протокола в настройках сайта. Для изображений используются относительные ссылки: <img src="/images/units/icon_special_general2.png">. Для js - абсолютные, с правильным указанием протокола (пробел добавлен только здесь, иначе протокол не видно): <script type="text/javascript" src="https ://ru.test.tsomaps.com/wp-content/themes/tsomaps/js/generator/typeface-0.15-patched.js"></script>. В настройках сайтов также указаны ссылки с https. Одна из проблемных страниц (на тестовом домене): https://ru.test.tsomaps.com/tools/generator/

Comment: У меня таких ошибок нет. Попробуйте вот эти советы: https://procomputer24.ru/kak-ispravit-oshibku-err_spdy_protocol_error-v-google-chrome/

Comment: И еще - как у вас серверная секция объявлена? Поставьте туда http2: `listen     443 ssl http2;`. spdy - устаревший протокол.

Comment: Серверная секция так и объявлена. Советы пробовал, не помогают. Пробовал также заходить с разных компьютеров, даже с чистой системы - везде одни и те же ошибки. Причем при первом входе обычно все хорошо или почти хорошо, ошибки начинают активно появляться либо после перемещений по сайту, либо после обновления страницы через ctrl+f5 (без учета кеша).

Comment: Я бы еще выкинул для проверки все из ваших настроек ssl, кроме первых 3 строчек. nignx и без этого работает.

Comment: Попробовал - без изменений :( Возникла мысль: а остальные настройки nginx (не относящиеся к ssl напрямую) не могут влиять?

Comment: Я не понимаю, откуда у вас протокол spdy

Comment: Почему то для загрузки картинок и js файлов хром использует spdy, а для всего остального - http2... Видимо проблема где-то здесь, пошел разбираться как это решить...

Comment: да у меня хром и никких проблем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался в итоге (когда уже нашел обходные пути) проблема оказалась вот в этих 3 опциях:

```
client_body_timeout 10;
reset_timedout_connection on;
send_timeout 2;
```

Причем отключение их по очереди и изменение таймаутов проблему не решает, только отключение всех 3 сразу.